# UnityEngine Can't Deserialize Sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

i working on a save system for my game. Basically, i was using JsonUtilty for saving system but it didn't help me because i want to save a list with ScriptableObjects. I was saving and loading correctly but when i restart the editor/computer it wasn't loading.

```
NullReferenceException
UnityEngine.Sprite.get_bounds () (at <4014a86cbefb4944b2b6c9211c8fd2fc>:0)
(wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,object)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider.GetValue (System.Object target) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/ExpressionValueProvider.cs:111)
Rethrow as JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'bounds' on 'UnityEngine.Sprite'.
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider.GetValue (System.Object target) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/ExpressionValueProvider.cs:115)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CalculatePropertyDetails (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty property, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter& propertyConverter, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Object target, System.Boolean& useExistingValue, System.Object& currentValue, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract& propertyContract, System.Boolean& gottenCurrentValue, System.Boolean& ignoredValue) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:1118)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty property, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter propertyConverter, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Object target) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:1014)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject (System.Object newObject, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.String id) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:2433)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:502)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:309)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty property, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter propertyConverter, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Object target) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:1052)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject (System.Object newObject, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.String id) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:2433)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:502)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:309)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList (System.Collections.IList list, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, System.String id) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:1712)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.Object existingValue, System.String id) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:926)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:311)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty property, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter propertyConverter, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Object target) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:1052)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject (System.Object newObject, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.String id) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:2433)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:502)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:309)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:202)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs:904)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs:883)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs:831)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs:787)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value) (at /root/repo/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs:720)
SaveGameManager.LoadGame () (at Assets/Scripts/SaveSystem/SaveGameManager.cs:40)
GameController.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Reqs/GameController.cs:39)
```

My SaveManager.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static class SaveGameManager
    {

        public const string SaveDirectory = "/SaveDataIdle/";
        public const string FileName = "SaveGame.sav";
        
        public static UnityAction OnSaveGame;
        public static UnityAction OnLoadGame;

        public static bool SaveGame()
        {
            var dir = Application.persistentDataPath + SaveDirectory;
            OnSaveGame?.Invoke();
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GameController.Instance.GameData, Formatting.Indented,new JsonSerializerSettings{ ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
            File.WriteAllText(dir + FileName, json);
            
            return true;
            
        }
        
        

        public static void LoadGame()
        {
            string fullPath = Application.persistentDataPath + SaveDirectory + FileName;
            GameData tempData = new GameData();

            if (File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                string json = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
                tempData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameData>(json);
                
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Save file cant be found");
            }

            GameController.Instance.GameData = tempData;
            OnLoadGame?.Invoke();
            Debug.Log("Loaded Successfully");
        }
    }
```

So i decided to switch to Newtonsoft Json.Net and now everything works well. The problem is i kept getting this error when i tried to load my game.
Actually, it loads the sprites to my UI but keep getting this error everytime. What should i do now?